# Force.com Architecture Whitepaper

Tags: apex, trigger, java, architecture, oracle

Are there any other technical resources besides this whitepaper that describes how things work under the hood at SFDC?

[The Force.com Multitenant Architecture](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Multi_Tenant_Architecture)

[PDF version](http://developerforce.s3.amazonaws.com/whitepapers/WP_Force-MT_101508_PRINT.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I know I may be 3 years late.

Here's what I've found anyways:

- [Multitenancy overview](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_concepts_multitenancy_and_metadata.htm)
- [Presentation from a Dreamforce event](https://www.salesforce.com/video/1768346/)
- [Multitenant Whitepaper](https://www.developerforce.com/media/ForcedotcomBookLibrary/Force.com_Multitenancy_WP_101508.pdf) (this is the one cited at the presentation)
- [Multitenant Architecture](https://developer.salesforce.com/ja/wiki/multi_tenant_architecture)

I hope this resources may help!

Comment: @identigral that's already reported in the question